# How to continuesly run PowerShell commands from Python thread?

Tags: python, powershell

I want to get my screen brightness and have a tkinter scale to set the brightness myself. I need PowerShell commands for getting the screen brightness and setting it. I already know how to do that, but I suppose the thread imports PowerShell (starts it like in cmd, takes a while) and after that runs the command and closes the PowerShell and opens it again. This method is slow and I can see from the TaskManager that the process takes about 30% CPU performance instead of the few percents it takes usually.

This is how I get the brightness and set the brightness

```
import os

while True:
    os.system("powershell Get-Ciminstance -Namespace root/WMI -ClassName WmiMonitorBrightness >brightness.txt")
    brightness_file = open("brightness.txt", "r")
    #This is the brightness value 0-100 as string
    brightness_now = brightness_file.read().split()[5]
    brightness_file.close()

    #Some code that isn't relative to this problem
    #The wanted birghtness is called now brightness_value

    #Setting the brightness
    os.system("powershell (Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(1,"+str(brightness_value)+")")
```

This works in other ways but it's not an efficient way. Can I somehow like import PowerShell to one thread so it never again needs to open PowerShell?

I tried something like this
    import os

```
#Import powershell
os.system("powershell")
#Get the brightness
os.system("Get-Ciminstance -Namespace root/WMI -ClassName WmiMonitorBrightness >brightness.txt")
```

But it just opens PowerShell in cmd and doesn't continue the code.

Comment: Why would you want to shell out to PowerShell when there is a [WMI module for Python](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/tutorial.html)?